# Issue with ClickHouse Connection to Amazon MQ for RabbitMQ via AMQPS

Tags: openssl, rabbitmq, clickhouse, amazon-mq

I'm seeking assistance with a connection issue between ClickHouse (version 23.8.2.7) and Amazon MQ. We recently transitioned our RabbitMQ instance to Amazon MQ, which exclusively supports AMQPS. To accommodate this, I updated the rabbitmq_address setting in ClickHouse to utilize the AMQPS schema. However, upon restarting the ClickHouse server, I encountered the following error in the log file:

```
<Debug> StorageRabbitMQ (table_name): Trying to restore connection to :0
<Error> StorageRabbitMQ (table_name): Library error report: Secure connection cannot be established: libssl.so cannot be loaded
```

I already tried to reinstall both OpenSSL and ClcikHouse, but the error persisted.

Could anyone provide insights into what might be causing this error and suggest potential solutions to resolve it?